# How to update multiple users with form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use `form_for` to create a form and update multiple users.

Let's say each user has `:id` and `:name`. I would like the `POST` parameters to be:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Leo"
    }
    ......
  ]
}
```

The form looks like(`[]` means input fields):

```
Users

1 [   Bob    ]
2 [   Leo    ]
3 [          ]
```

How does the `form_for` code looks like?

Comment: I pretty sure, you not gonna able to make it without JS. You will need to multiple selector for users then append into form as an of array data.

Comment: Thanks @7urkm3n. No js required, no selector required.

Comment: fields_for is really the option oyu are looking for rather than form_for or form_with but I believe fields_for may need a parent object in a form_for. Maybe have a look here https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Answer (score 0):

```
form_tag your_url, method: :post do |f|
  @users.each do |user|
    label_tag user.id
    hidden_field_tag "users[][id]", user.id
    text_field_tag "users[][first_name]", user.first_name
  end
end
```

I think it will pass parameters as you want, but the hard thing is how to show detail error messages for each user